# creating a list from a column with multiple lines

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, for-loop, split

I have a Pandas data frame that in one column called SourceDocument I have multiple lines of data in each cell (separated by \n).

SourceDocuments

PRDS-002039\nPRDS-001952\nPRDS-001956

I would like to run a for loop that reads each row and then separates these lines into a list. Eventually, I wanna have a dictionary where the value is the list of split items.
for example:

SourceID

546785:    ['PRDS-002039','PRDS-001952','PRDS-001956']

The dict keys(546785) are generated through another for loop
I wrote the below code but can't figure out how to do the split row-by-row

```
valuez=[]    
for j in range (0,ABP215.shape[0]):
       valuez.append(ABP215['SourceDocuments'][j].split('\n'))
```

APB215 is the Pandaas dataframe name.

I get this error:

**AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'**

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe change `Validation Report` to `SourceDocuments`? But `df['SourceDocuments'].str.split('\n')` is enough I think.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post there sample (small) input dataframe? From where the dictionary keys come from? (546785)

Comment: Edited my Qs. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Perhaps there are some floats in your df? Have u checked dtypes?

Comment: Try to apply str to the SourceDocuments: valuez.append(df['SourceDocuments'].apply(str)[j].split('\n'))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Everyone for their help, and my apologies for not being straight clear on my Q. Here is the answer put together with the community's help.

```
SourceDocumentID=np.arange(1001,1001+ABP215.shape[0],1)
SourceDocumentID=list(SourceDocumentID)

keyz=[]
for i in range(0,len(SourceDocumentID)): # building 
  keyz.append(SourceDocumentID[i])
valuez=[]
for j in range (0,ABP215.shape[0]):
  valuez.append(ABP215['Source Document'].apply(str)[j].split('\n'))
sourcedocuments={k:v for k,v in zip(keyz,valuez) }

SourceDoc=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sourcedocuments,orient='index')
```